# Change permissions

Tags: unix, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I use s3cmd to upload files to Amazon s3. It is a super application. The only problem is I still need to log into the web interface and change the permissions of the file to "Authorized Users" and grant Read on it.

Is there a way I can change the permissions via a terminal and have it be Authorized Users?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Bucket Policy. Set Bucket Policy on that bucket which set Public Read permission on the object. So what every you upload from s3cmd it will set read permission on that object automatically.

I am a developer of Bucket Explorer (Amazon S3 Tool). If s3cmd does not have option to set S3 Bucket Policy then you can try Bucket Explore. and This tool also have feature of Bucket Default, using this feature you can set desire permission automatically on newly uploaded s3. files.

Comment: I don't want to have Public Read though. I only want to grant Read to Authorized Users. Can I do that in the Bucket Policy? Not sure how I would go about that. I have Bucket Explorer. Are you saying I could specify the bucket default as Read for Authorized Users?

Comment: If User is Registered AWS S3 User, then you can do it, But if you want to give authorized access to none s3 user then you can generate signed url and that you have to create manually. If you want to share your complete bucket to AWS Authorized user then you can also do that.

Comment: "If you want to share your complete bucket to AWS Authorized user then you can also do that." - how would I do that?